# How to verify assignment is done without error in string?

Tags: c++, string

What if I want to validate assignment operation?
link http://ideone.com/pVE40h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string str;
        int p;
    if  (p = 2)              // 1 case 
        cout << "assigned";
    else
        cout << "not assigned";

    if(str = "my string")   // 2 case 
        cout << "assigned"
    else
        cout << "not assigned";
return 0;
}
```

My question is if case 1 is working then case 2 should and if not then why? It should be that simple?
I know everything you guys are posting here try and catch stuff but I think I should work that way??

Comment: Read a reference. It throws if there's a problem.

Comment: what if i want to check from my end?

Comment: Then catch the exception, just like any other exception you might be able to handle.

Comment: possible but not good idea though...

Comment: you may wanna use == not = in your if-statement

Comment: You can validate the assignment, but who will validate the validation?

Comment: why don't you use a string comparison tool?

Comment: because i m not doing that in case 1?? even if it is string i think it should be there?

Comment: cant we have such things like if user have applied their own validation then class(string) should not apply it's native validation or its kind of stupid? :P

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    str = "my_string";
    return 0;
}
catch(...)
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: my question is if case 1 is working then case 2 should and if not then why? it should be that simple? i know everything you guys are posting here try and catch and other stuff but i think it should work that way??

Comment: You changed your code from what it was. Now case 1 is `int` which is implicitly convertible to bool, and case 2 is `std::string` which is not.

Comment: yes you are right @Matt McNabb but ans this question if there is any?

Comment: @rupesh.yadav sorry I'm not sure what else you are asking